# How to search using find command in external hard disk

Tags: terminal, find

I have an external hard disk. I have to search for a folder called `Visa` in that external Hard disk named `ASTUTE`. There might be multiple `VISA` folder but I want to search for all of them.

I navigated to external Hard Disk using `cd` and then typed `find / -name VISA` but I got lot of permission denied errors. Do I need to run it as super user? Is this right command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `find / -name VISA`,  the `/` always refer to the root directory of your Mac and not the external drive because it's an absolute path. It's the same on any UNIX-Based system.

What you want, is to specify the folder where OSX has mounted your drive:

```
find /Volumes/ASTUTE -name VISA
```

And since you only want to search for folder you can use the `-type` params (`d` is for directory):

```
find /Volumes/ASTUTE -type d -name VISA
```

`/Volumes` is the default folder where OSX mount UBS drives.

Like Pan Long said, you can do the same by navigating to the drive itself:

```
cd /Volumes/ASTUTE
find . -name VISA
```

Here `.` refer to the relative path, wich is `/Volumes/ASTUTE`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have navigated to the destination folder, you only need to search in current directory. Change the command to `find . -name VISA`